# Trying to get top 20 user statistics MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 100 user in database
Each user have started 5 course.
Each course have statistics.

Course example:

```
{
    userId: user1@gmail.com,
    score: 50
}
```

database schema:

```
{
  userId: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: Users
  },
  score: Number
}
```

Each user have 5 similar document in database, as I mentioned above.

I tried aggregation (group) with date: "$last" command but I didn't get any info.

I want to find top 20 unique user with their latest course result and sorted by score (high score).

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

Comment: can you provide the schema of the database also? curently questation is not clear to me.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I edited and you can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your schema,
aggregate query:

```
[
 {
  "$group": {
   "_id": "$userId",
   "score": {
    "$last": "$score"
   }
  }
 }
]
```

will get you all the unique users(*Group By*) with last record of `score`.
and as you wanted to get only *20* users , we can put a [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) condition:

```
[
 {
  "$group": {
   "_id": "$userId",
   "score": {
    "$last": "$score"
   }
  }
 },{
 $limit:20
 }
]
```